# How 7 is the right answer and not 6 in this output

Tags: c++, fstream, data-handling

Assume that the file SCHOOLS.DAT is created
with the help of objects of class SCHOOLS, which is defined below:
class SCHOOLS

```
class SCHOOLS
{
int SCode; // School Code
char SName[20]; // School Name
int NOT; // Number of Teachers in the school
public:
    void Display()
     {cout<<SCode<<"#"<<SName<<"#"<<NOT<<endl;}
      int RNOT(){return NOT;}
     };
```

**Question**
Find the output of the following C++ code considering that the binary file
SCHOOLS.DAT exists on the hard disk with the following records of 10 schools of
the class SCHOOLS as declared in the previous .

SCode SName NOT

1001 Brains School 100

1003 Child Life School 115

1002 Care Share School 300

1006 Educate for Life School 50

1005 Guru Shishya Sadan 195

1004 Holy Education School 140

1010 Rahmat E Talim School 95

1008 Innovate Excel School 300

1011 Premier Education School 200

1012 Uplifted Minds School 100

```
void main()
{
 fstream SFIN;
 SFIN.open("SCHOOLS.DAT",ios::binary|ios::in);
 SCHOOLS S;
 SFIN.seekg(5*sizeof(S));
 SFIN.read((char*)&S, sizeof(S));
 S.Display();
 cout<<"Record :"<<SFIN.tellg()/sizeof(S) + 1<<endl;
 SFIN.close();
}
```

**Output**
1004#Holy Education School#140
Record :7

**My Question** How did Record is 7 and not 6.

My approach as the value of S will be 24 . Got it after adding the 2 byte of int Scode, 2 bytes of int NOT, 20 bytes of char SName[20].

so value of sizeof(S) will be 24 and value of SFIN.tellg will be 120 dividing them will give us 5 and then we have to add 1. So it will be 6 right?

Comment: it should be 24 should it be?

Comment: `6 * sizeof(S) / sizeof(S) + 1` is 7, not 6.

Comment: I might have not understood what do you mean by that.. Will you please just breakdown for me with a good understandable explanation as why the right answer is 7. Consider if I have never approached my above approach. Please I need a good explanation as I am a very beginner to this. And tomorrow its coming in my exam

Comment: how we came to know that SFIN.tellg() will return 6 and not 5

Comment: Let's `X=sizeof(S)`. Then `6 * X / X + 1 = (6 * (X / X)) + 1 = (6 * 1) + 1 = 6 + 1 = 7`.

Comment: Lightness.... I might have not understood your question sir

Comment: @SurajGiri You moved past five, and then read one. 5 + 1 = 6.

Comment: Kamil how do we know 6 is the return of SFIN.tellg()

Comment: `seekg(5 * sizeof(S))` - you are at 5th `SCHOOL`, `read(... sizeof(S))` - you are at 6th `SCHOOL` after you  read. `read` advances the position in the file. So if you start at `5 * sizeof(S)` and read `sizeof(S)`, the position in the file increments by `sizoef(S)` so you end at `6 * sizeof(S)`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think the file actually is binary ("the binary file SCHOOLS.DAT "), although the contents listing looks like it's text.

Comment: @molbdnilo If that is true, then the question should clearly state the contents of the file, exactly.

Comment: But you do `tellg()/sizeof(S)`. So if `tellg=6*sizeof(S)`, that's `6 * sizeof(S) / sizeof(S)`. That's 6. Then you add 1. `SFIN.tellg()/sizeof(S) + 1`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I learned it from my c++ teacher in my school sir

Comment: Perhaps then you should ask your C++ teacher for further help on this project. That is, after all, what you pay him/her for! Either way, good luck.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion  if anyone had . kamil is right file is actually binary

Comment: Thank you so much @KamilCuk your explanation resolved my query . Thank you

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes sir/mam I'll approach my sir for further explanation. thanks

Comment: What about the 16 characters on the top line of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to think about the actual value of `sizeof(S)`; just treat it as a constant K.

You initially seek to the position 5*K.  Then you read K bytes from the file, leaving you at the position 6*K.  That means the expression `SFIN.tellg()/sizeof(S) + 1` is equivilent to 6*K/K + 1.  K/K is equal to 1 for any K, so that further simplifies to 6*1 + 1, which equals 7.